# События в теории c#

Tags: c#

Господа, помогите, разобраться, не смог ничего толкового выгуглить по такому вот вопросу: как в теории работает система, которая получает события типа нажатия на кнопку мыши? Я имею в виду то, что в процессе написания кода я лишь привязываю обработчик к этому событию, но каким образом это событие генерируется? Ведь при создании собственных событий мы пишем определенный метод, который при вызове генерирует события, и те в свою очередь вызывают необходимые обработчики. Но в то же время я не могу понять, какой метод генерирует событие щелчка мыши, к которому (событию) мы в дальнейшем привязываем обработчик. И как и чем этот метод вызывается?

Если вкратце, то суть вопроса в том, что когда я нажимаю на кнопку мыши, в .Net вызывает определенный метод, в котом генерируется определенное событие, к которому прикручены определенные обработчики. Но что за метод вызывается первым, и кто его вызывает? Простите, если вопрос идиотский, но очень хочу разобраться.

Comment: Событие идет из недр мыши в определенный порт компутера, затем оно обрабатывается по прерыванию и отправляется в ядро операционной системы. 

Ядро сообщает всем желающим об этом событии. Библиотека .net берет это событие и делают из него удобный объект. 

Далее библиотека отправляет этот объект всем желающим(подписанным на это событие).

Comment: Спасибо. То есть получается, что Net вызывает определенный метод, который бы генерировал событие OnMouseClick?

Comment: @polyakov_s, Скорее .net получает информацию о клике мыши, переводит его в локальные координаты для окна, определяет, куда попал клик, и вызывает метод OnMouseClick у объекта, в который попали.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Так как .NET Winforms это высокоуровневая обёртка над WinAPI, то там внутри всё базируется на обработке сообщений. При кликании мышкой на экране система посылает форме (и контролу) сообщение. В цикле обработки сообщений оно обрабатывается и вызывается соответсвующий метод.

Если вам интересно, можете поковыряться в исходниках фреймворка и разобраться, что откуда берётся. Вот, например, откуда берётся `OnClick`:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case NativeMethods.WM_REFLECT + NativeMethods.WM_COMMAND:
                if (NativeMethods.Util.HIWORD(m.WParam) == NativeMethods.BN_CLICKED) {
                    Debug.Assert(!GetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint), "Shouldn't get BN_CLICKED when UserPaint");
                    if (!ValidationCancelled) {
                        OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);
                    }                        
                }
                break;
            case NativeMethods.WM_ERASEBKGND:
                DefWndProc(ref m);
                break;
            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам пользователь **mantigatos** все сказал. Для дальнейшего изучения событий под Win - читайте про WinAPI, для .Net - ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО ПРОЧИТАЙТЕ про delegate - ... .